# margin-right and left works in different way regards to overflow-float divs

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

```
    <body>
        <div class="content">
           <div class="content-sidebar">
                content-sidebar
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                content-main
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

above is html code, and below is css code.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content-sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.content-main {
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

overflow hidden property creates new block formatting context in the .content-main, so .content-sidebar and .content-main are totally in different context.

so I thought that margin-right:30px on .content-main would work.

but it is working only in .content-sidebar (margin-left).

edited))

plus, I checked it with chrome dev tools, and margin-right on main div interacts with the browser. (not with the sidebar). but floated sidebar interacts with main div. why is that..?

Comment: @HendryTanaka padding works in the same way. I checked it with chrome dev tools, and margin-right on main div interacts with the browser. (not with the sidebar). but floated sidebar interacts with main div. why is that..?

Comment: @HendryTanaka why are you giving that link? that seems irrelevant.

Comment: @jwkoo could explain your issue better?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It was for another question @jwkoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to point out is that you say:

> overflow hidden property creates new block formatting context in the .content-main, so .content-sidebar and .content-main are totally in different context.

That is incorrect. The `overflow hidden` property establishes a new block formatting context *for its contents*. It doesn't affect the context that it is in. So `.content-sidebar` and `.content-main` are in the same context. This is relevant for the quote below.

[CSS 2.2 section 9.5 Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float) says:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element narrower than defined by section 10.3.3.

Here we have **"must not overlap the margin box of any floats"** That's why margin-left on the sidebar spaces the main section away from it. But we also have **"make the border box of said element narrower"** - Note the border box, not the margin box, so there's no requirement to position the margin of main so that it doesn't overlap with the floated sidebar.

Comment: appreciate for fixing my misunderstood concepts.