# left margin not working on overflow:auto element following the float

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I'm currently trying to create a two column layout where the left column is floated and the right column restrains the float by forming a new block formatting context. That works. Later, I try to put some visible space between the left column and the content of right column. If I set left padding on the right column, it works. I also try to replace the left padding with left margin on the right column, and think they would have the same effect. However, to my surprise, the left margin is not working at all

I reproduce the problem with the following code. Notice that the example in the middle, setting the left margin on the right column does not really push it away from the left column

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}

.container + .container {
  margin-top: 20px
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  overflow: auto;
  background: skyblue;
  height: 100%;
}

.with-padding {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.with-margin {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left column, floated</div>
  <div class="right with-padding">
    <p>left padding works</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left column, floated</div>
  <div class="right with-margin">
    <p>left margin dost not work</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left column, floated</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="with-margin">
      <p>left margin works on the wrapper div</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did search for this topic on the internet but don't find too much relevant information. I suspect this might be related to the concept of block formatting context (BFC). If I understand correctly, margin represents distance between the target box's outer edge and containing BFC's inner border.

If we set margin on a box which itself forms its own BFC, then margin shouldn't work? So in the third example, I place the text into an extra wrapper and set margin on that wrapper, and it looks like left margin work again. However, this is just my guess.

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395507/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical point here is that

> The **border box** of ... an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with overflow other than visible) must not overlap the margin box of any floats ...

[*CSS 2.2 Section 9.5 Floats*](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#bfc-next-to-float)

So the margin, which lies outside the border box, of such a BFC can (and in your second case does) overlap with the float, but padding, which lies inside the border box, cannot.

Comment: thanks, I read your excerpt: "The border box of ... an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context ... must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself."  I don't quite get how it is applied in my case: The floated left column does not have any margin? Also, the excerpt only mentions the behaviour of **border box** of the new BFC, but it does not mention anything about **margin box** of the new BFC. It looks like margin box of BFC overlaps border box of float, but where is this behavior specified?

Comment: I also read your answer in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395507/10003645. but i think that's a totally different scenario. In that case, I understand why the margin box of the float would push it away from the other new BFC box, but I still don't get why the margin box of new BFC won't push it away from margin box or border box of the float, given they are under the same parent BFC.

Comment: 1. The float has zero width margins, but it has a margin box that surrounds the border, padding and content boxes, so the right edge of the margin box is on the right side of the floated element. 2. The quoted excerpt is the limiting factor. The BFC's margin box is not limited by the spec. It is free to overlap or not as is required. Specs don't define things that don't impose limits.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining it. Is this overlapping between the margin box of floated element and margin box of next new BFC the same behavior as the well-known margin collapse. I always thought only the vertical margin would collapse until I hit into this problem

Comment: @hafan96 - No, margin collapse is a completely unrelated thing.

Comment: got it. One last question: in this situation, which do you think is a better way for pushing the content of right column away from left column? 1) add padding to the right column 2) create a inner div inside the right column (BFC) and wrap all the content, set the margin on the inner div to push it aways from the parent div (right column), therefore also move away from the left column?

Comment: Whichever works for you in any given situation. There really isn't a "better" way.